# asp:imagebutton, change image from javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

How can i change the image of an image button clientside, on click.

I have tried this:

```
function changetoDownload(theId) {
   $(theId.id).delay(2000)
   .queue(function (next) { $(theId).attr("ImageURL", "Images/Apps/free.png"); next(); });
}

<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" OnClick="Button7_Click" OnClientClick="changetoDownload(this.id);" ImageUrl="Images/download.gif" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 1):

JQuery runs at client side. The reason your javascript isn't working is because the "asp" tag is rendered server side and once displayed on the client side the markup changes to HTML. You are referencing the ImageURL attribute which doesn't exist in HTML it would be the "src" attribute. You can check this by deploying your code and then using "View Source" in your browser.

Comment: View source shows that its rendered as: <input type="image" name="ctl00$MainContent$ImageButton1" id="MainContent_ImageButton1" src="Images/download.gif" onclick="changetoDownload(this.id);" /

Comment: From there you can see that the image link is being rendered as "src". Jasper above has the correct solution and from your post you can see that the ID is MainContent_ImageButton1 so just put that in place of ImageButton1 in the code example above.

Comment: I up ticked this because it is true and contains useful, relevant information but alas it is not sufficient for me.  I can see the src attribute and innerHTML fields are correctly updated in the browser debugger but the old image continues to be displayed! :(

Answer (score 1):

```
//target all `<input type="image" />` elements and bind a `click` event handler to them
$('input[type="image"]').on('click', function () {

    //change the `src` of this element
    $(this).attr('src', 'Images/Apps/free.png');
});
```

Note that `.on()` is new as of jQuery 1.7 and in this case is the same as `.bind()`.

I'm not sure how ASP.net will render your button but you can target it using the ID of the element:

```
$('#MainContent_ImageButton1').on('click', function () {

    //change the `src` of this element
    $(this).attr('src', 'Images/Apps/free.png');
});
```

You can check the source of your document in a browser to see if that is the actual rendered ID of the ASP button.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/PQ4fp/

Comment: OP is using master page as told by him in comments. So I think, ID is not traceable in ur case.

Comment: $('#MainContent_ImageButton1').on('click', function () {

              //change the `src` of this element
              $(this).attr('src', 'Images/Apps/free.png');
          });

Comment: OP posted the HTML source of the element and it's an `input` tag with the ID of `MainContent_ImageButton1`. So either of my selectors above should work (unless the ID may be changed by the framework, that I'm not sure about).

Comment: the above i posted in comment are working, when using MainContent_ImageButton1 as ID. BUT can i do that with multiple buttons? without making a function for each ImageButton?

Comment: @ClemenGronver In that case you should either add a class to the elements to group them together so you can select them like this: `$('.my-custom-class').on('click', function () { ... });`, or you can use the first selector in my answer `$('input[type="image"]')` which selects all the `<input type="image" />` elements (like your button). You can also select multiple elements at the same time separating the selectors by commas: `$('#MainContent_ImageButton1, #MainContent_ImageButton2, #MainContent_ImageButton3')...`

Comment: I have 12 diferrent imagebutton, and the image shall first change when the specific button is pressed ( and only change on that button )

Comment: `MainContent_ImageButton1` is a HardCode ID, Please avoid it. Are you going to change the code in case ID changes in future ?

Comment: You can check my answer to get this done in case of multiple Image button controls.

Comment: @PankajGarg If the framework can change the ID without your knowledge, that's one thing, but avoiding the use of IDs because at some point you may decide to change it doesn't seem very valid.

Comment: @ClemenGronver `$('input[type="image"]')` will select every single one of these buttons on the page... The square brackets signify an attribute selector, so this is looking for all the `input` elements that have a `type` attribute set to `image`.

Comment: I just personally don't prefer ID in the functions, as it can be changed by you. For more details, will you like you check my answer ?

Answer (score 1):

> It is very easy in JavaScript

**HTML Code**

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="img" runat="server"  OnClientClick="return abc(this);" />
```

---

**JavaScript Code**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function abc(ImageID) {
    var img = document.getElementById(ImageID.id);
    img.src = "Jellyfish.jpg";
    return false;
}

</script>
```

Comment: Since jQuery is being used, you might as well take advantage of the easy binding system rather than using inline JS, which can be a nightmare to maintain since you may have to update many pieces of code rather than a single piece of code that does all your event handling.

Comment: I can keep this function in JavaScript file and same can be reused. FYI, Please check the Tags and Title.

Comment: I have code similar to the above but, while I can see that it is indeed changing the src in the debugger, the old image continues to be displayed.  Something more is required it seems :(